# Woocommerce stock QTY doesn't change but price does on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I implemented some custom code to set the default starting QTY of stocks to 2, but now when I try changing the QTY in the cart the prices change to reflect the value but the QTY reverts back to 2. How do I fix that? Below is my code I'm using in the functions file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'ADS_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );

function ADS_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $args['input_value']        = 2;    // Starting value
    $args['max_value']      = 100;  // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']      = 2;    // Minimum value
    return $args;
}
```

Edit: remove input_value and it works.

Comment: You want fix quantity 2?

Comment: No, I see my error now, quite silly.